# Node.js encrypting and decrypting is doubling file size

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I am creating a Node.js application that can encrypt and decrypt image files. However when my code is run I get varying results: Sometimes the decrypted image looks like the original at the top but the bottom half looks corrupted, sometimes the decrypted image is completely there but looks like it was heavily compressed and sometimes the decrypted image is too corrupt to open. Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1PVn.png) that demonstrates this. The only thing these results have in common is the encrypted and decrypted images are double the file size of the original image.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');

var path = 'C:\\Users\\' + windowsUserName + '\\Desktop\\image';
    var fileExtension = '.jpg';
    var password = '1234';
    var algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';

    var image = fs.createReadStream(path + fileExtension);

    var encryptedImage = fs.createWriteStream(path + ' encrypted' + fileExtension);
    var decryptedImage = fs.createWriteStream(path + ' decrypted' + fileExtension);

    var encrypt = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password);
    var decrypt = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password);

    image.pipe(encrypt).pipe(encryptedImage);
    image.pipe(encrypt).pipe(decrypt).pipe(decryptedImage);
```

How do I fix the image corruption and file size doubling?

Comment: AES-CBC should be used with `createCipherIv` not `createCipher`.

Comment: I don't really understand how initialization vector's work so if you could tell me more that would be great! The answer I selected seems to work so could you explain to me why I should implement them?

Comment: Because without them your encryption is insecure and doesn't really work.  Look up ECB mode on Wikipedia and look at the penguin.

Comment: The part I really don't get is this line: `"it is important that an initialization vector is never reused under the same key"`. If I were to change my current code to use `createCipherIv` instead of `createCipher` wouldn't I be reusing the IV all the time?

Comment: Yes, that's why you should always generate a new random IV every time you encrypt.  Getting encryption right is difficult, it's very delicate.  The code you have, with respect, is pretty mediocre.

Comment: That does seem like trouble. Since the function `createDecipheriv` exists does that mean I have to save the IV for each file I encrypt. Lets say I have 300,000 files; do I need save a list of each IV - file pair before doing anything with encryption? Since this is just going to go back and forth do you know any good resources/examples for encryption in node?

Comment: Just store the IV in the file. It's not a secret value, it just has to be unpredictable. Don't look at programming language specific encryption tutorials - they're more likely to be wrong. Look at general encryption guides. You might also find [this repository](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples) of use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179955/discussion-between-hei-and-luke-joshua-park).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to decrypt the cypher before it is finished. If you wait until the pipe is done and read the encrypted file, it should not be garbled:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');

var path = 'file path';
    var fileExtension = '.jpg';
    var password = '1234';
    var algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc';

    var image = fs.createReadStream(path + fileExtension);
    var encryptedImage = fs.createWriteStream(path + ' encrypted' + fileExtension);
    var encrypt = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password);
    image.pipe(encrypt).pipe(encryptedImage);

    encryptedImage.on("finish", function(){
        var decrypt = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password);
        var decryptedImage = fs.createWriteStream(path + ' decrypted' + fileExtension);
        var encryptedImage = fs.createReadStream(path + ' encrypted' + fileExtension);
        encryptedImage.pipe(decrypt).pipe(decryptedImage);
    })
```

Comment: I thought I had ruled out that possibility in one of my tests but apparently I did it wrong, thanks.